# ng-disable is not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.firstName =false;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.firstName =!$scope.firstName ;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <button ng-click=toggle()>ToGgLe</button>
      <input type="text" ng-disabled="{{firstName}}">
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here i'm trying to toggle the input field with the function as shown in code.I can see the value changing in the DOM but it is not rendered by angular properly...input is not toggling...Help me out...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do string interpolation, as [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) accepts a `expression` pass direct `firstName` .

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="firstName">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.firstName =false;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.firstName =!$scope.firstName ;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <button ng-click=toggle()>ToGgLe</button>
      <input type="text" ng-disabled="firstName">
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use interpolation operator `{{}}`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.firstName =false;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.firstName =!$scope.firstName ;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <button ng-click=toggle()>ToGgLe</button>
      <input type="text" ng-disabled="firstName">
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```